# Can't get cookies to send with request in Express 4

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, express, express-4

Here's my initial config:

```
var session         = require('express-session');
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(session({
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: false,
  genid: function(req) {
    return Services.misc.generateUUID()
  },
  secret: secret.toString()
}));
app.use(cookieParser(secret));
```

Then in my controller (it's routed through a dead simple router to a controller, which then renders appropriate actions based on a Rails-like naming convention) I'll do something like this:

```
var TestController = {
  noaction: function(req, res) {
    var locals = {
      billy: 'the goat'
    }

    console.log('req session'.red, req.session);
    res.cookie('test_cookie', 'Wu Tang Clan');

    this.services.render.view(req, res, this, 200, locals);
  }

module.exports = TestController;
```

Note that `this.services.render.view` is just a service so that I don't have to write `res.render('./app/controllers' + controller + '/' + action)`

Note the res.cookie line in the controller ([docs on express.js](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie)). That's what the official docs say to do and in fact, it's then set in the browser:

[image]

However, the line above res.cookie is a log and I would imagine we'd have `test_cookie` in it, but:

[image]

All I get is a standard blank cookie every time, even though it's set browser-side and supposedly sending.

My question is: **How do I properly set and receive cookies in Express 4?**

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer: Every time nodemon restarts the server to propagate code changes, the sessions are cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be ok, as dsp_099 said, it is probably the nodemon.
The express-session saves the data in-memory, so when you restart your server (with nodemon automatically) all the memory data is reseted.

I you wanna persist the session data even if node is restarted, may i suggest you use redis-session (Redis Database)